# Nodejs application does not work without network connection

Tags: node.js

We have a simple node application which connects to sql using mssql module to retrieve data. Everything works fine, when network connection is available. But, the application fails to connect to db when there is no network connection.

I have checked in different sites and found something about dns error when loopback address comes into picture. Not sure what would be the actual cause.

Error: getaddinfo ENOENT (when there is no network)

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: This is a local myssql right?

Comment: Yes, its local db, sql server. To add on, both sql db and application are in the same server.

Comment: Which version of node are you running? There is a known issue with dns.lookup that may be related (https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/25338) ... try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: I have not configured any dns lookup in the application. Do I need to do any? The node version used - v0.12.1.

Comment: Are you using 'localhost' to connect to sql?

Comment: I'm using sql server instance name, like machine name with sql server authentication.